# Shopify multiply product grid on same page

Tags: shopify

Looking for solution about how to add multiply product grid to a single template.
As for now, i added functionality to have collection selector and can see what i selected.
Even i can display own products for each section.

But the list contain empty ".filter" object, so i can not manipulate with filter on front.
The only collection that worked fine on some template - the collection which that template created for...
Other collections - has empty ".filter" object.

My direction of thinking now is to create own filter. But next usse most things for my shop is in meta fields. And im not familiar with it...

Trying to get ifo of object most time getting this

```
{{ product.metafields | json }}
{"error":"json not allowed for this object"}
```

Probably there is a proper way to get dump of object in liquid ?